# What is the first instance of people filing a petition against casting a character?

Tags: first-appearance, casting

These days people are very serious about the live action adaptation of their favorite character from comic books or novels. Some fans even file online petitions to request a change in the character's casting. For example. these days Ben Affleck's casting is in the news due to a petition filed against him online.

But my question is: what is the first occurrence of this kind of petition being filed against casting a character?

Comment: Down-vote reason will be appreciable. If it doesn't fit then i am ready to delete it.

Comment: It seems a fair question but quite hard to definitively answer.  What level of petition is noteworthy for example - how do you measure that.  This may be the reason for downvotes.

Comment: @iandotkelly i just asked for the first occurrence of a petition fired by common peoples against casting a character from novels or comic books. Any kind of petition are worthy just concerning for the older most which was filed before film release.

Comment: I know - just trying to explain the downvotes.  I think as long as there are verifyable references, its an ok question - e.g. the petition itself, a newspaper article referring to it. etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first time I heard about a popular internet based campaign against a casting decision was Daniel Craig as James Bond in Casino Royale.

For example, here is a page specifically set up to campaign against this decision:

[danielcraigisnotbond.com](http://www.danielcraigisnotbond.com/boycott_casino_royale.html)

And I found [a petition](http://www.petitiononline.com/CRAIG007/petition.html) (only 40 signaures though).

The internet campaigning against Daniel Craig was also thoroughly reported on the BBC film review radio show and podcast - the Kermode and Mayo Film Review.  I'll try to find an example of this.

Comment: And of course IMHO Daniel Craig was a great casting decision, particularly in Casino Royale.

Comment: Thank god nobody listened to those idiots. Next they will tell me *Roger Moore* is the best *Bond* of all. ;-)

Comment: The website danielcraigisnotbond.com dates from at least September 2006 when it said: "So keep those emails going, sign the petitions, and BOYCOTT this movie!" http://wayback.archive.org/web/20060901174939/http://danielcraigisnotbond.com/ // They linked to the KeepPierceOnAsBond Yahoo group which started in October 2004: http://wayback.archive.org/web/20060831202957/http://movies.groups.yahoo.com/group/KeepPierceOnAsBond/

Comment: Bit OT, but since you mentioned a dedicated web-site...  I remember several "EmmaWatsonHaters" sites and discussion boards, that despite the name, didn't really hate Emma Watson - just her playing Hermione Granger in Harry Potter, because she didn't fit the role ("too pretty" among  other things).